# Como dividir un campo en mysql en varias tablas

Tags: mysql

Hola a todos tengo la siguiente tabla en mysql

```
id      nombre
1.     item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7,item8,item9,item10        
2.     item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7,item8,item9,item10
```

Quisiera saber si hay forma de mostrar los items de un solo campo en dos tablas, algo así:

```
id             nombre1                            nombre2
1.     item1,item2,item3,item4,item5      item6,item7,item8,item9,item10        
2.     item1,item2,item3,item4,item5      item6,item7,item8,item9,item10
```

No importa el orden de los items lo importante es que se dividan en dos tablas.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el objetivo de esto? No comprendo lo que quieres. Tal vez lo que buscas es crear vistas sobre la tabla.

Comment: Me adhiero a la pregunta de @Jemonge, y también preguntar en que circunstancia se llega a esa forma de almacenar los datos, ya que la columna nombre tiene varios items en cada campo, y eso rompe con la primera forma normal. Sería bueno sacarnos estas dudas para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Obtengo la lista de aplicaciones instaladas en un móvil, que vendría ser los diferentes items, estos los guardo como una sola cadena, pero al momento de hacer reportes me gustaría mostrarlos en varias columnas en ves de una, eso era todo :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con `substring`, seleccionando los items por el separador, en este caso ',', y usando el índice positivo para mostrar los elementos de la parte izquierda y el negativo para mostrar los de la parte derecha.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  item VARCHAR(100)
);
INSERT INTO test (id, item) VALUES (1,'i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6,i7,i8,i9,i10');

CREATE TABLE test2 (
  id INT,
  item1 VARCHAR(50),
  item2 VARCHAR(50)
  );
```

---

**Query #1**
Si quieres mostrarlo al hacer la selección

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(item,',',5) AS item1,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(item,',',-5) AS item2
FROM test;

| item1          | item2           |
| -------------- | --------------- |
| i1,i2,i3,i4,i5 | i6,i7,i8,i9,i10 |
```

---

**Query #2**
Si quieres insertarlos en una nueva tabla

```
INSERT INTO test2 (
 SELECT id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(item,',',5),
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(item,',',-5)
  FROM test );
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #3**

```
SELECT * FROM test2;

| id  | item1          | item2           |
| --- | -------------- | --------------- |
| 1   | i1,i2,i3,i4,i5 | i6,i7,i8,i9,i10 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)